# How to get CPU vendor name programmatically for Android device?

Tags: android

I want to get programmatically manufacturer name or vendor name of CPU or processor used in Android device

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use below code

```
   Log.i("TAG", "SERIAL: " + Build.SERIAL);
Log.i("TAG","MODEL: " + Build.MODEL);
Log.i("TAG","ID: " + Build.ID);
Log.i("TAG","Manufacture: " + Build.MANUFACTURER);
Log.i("TAG","brand: " + Build.BRAND);
Log.i("TAG","type: " + Build.TYPE);
Log.i("TAG","user: " + Build.USER);
Log.i("TAG","BASE: " + Build.VERSION_CODES.BASE);
Log.i("TAG","INCREMENTAL " + Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL);
Log.i("TAG","SDK  " + Build.VERSION.SDK);
Log.i("TAG","BOARD: " + Build.BOARD);
Log.i("TAG","BRAND " + Build.BRAND);
Log.i("TAG","HOST " + Build.HOST);
Log.i("TAG","FINGERPRINT: "+Build.FINGERPRINT);
Log.i("TAG","Version Code: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
```

More information can be found here 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html